# Webtools and developer tools issue on Phalcon framework

Tags: php, phalcon

I installed phalcon 3.0.1-14 on an Ubuntu 14.04 box. Also installed Phalcon DevTools (3.0.1).
Initially, I enabled the webtools and when I visit that page, some warnings appear all the time:

```
Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in /home/pish/vendor/phalcon/devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php
Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in /home/pish/vendor/phalcon/devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools/views/index.phtml
```

I just ignored them and tried to create a model out of an existing table in the database. When I clicked on "Generate" button
I get the following error:

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception: ModelsController handler class cannot be loaded
```

and the model is not created. I tested creating a controller as well, but a similar error occurred and the controller
was not created either.

Finally, I created the model via the console `phalcon model users` and it was created successfully.

I noticed, though, that the validation function created by the developer tools doesn't work and causes the following
error when I try to create a user:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Mvc\Model::validate() must implement interface Phalcon\ValidationInterface, instance of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email given in...
```

My question is basically, is there something bad with the version of developer tools I installed that causes the problems
with the Webtools and the functions that are generated for models/controllers, etc.? Or I might have something wrong
in my system?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot bind an instance to a static closure

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/11029

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Mvc\Model::validate()

Fixed in the 3.0.x branch (will be released soon)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Mvc\Model::validate() must implement interface Phalcon\ValidationInterface, instance of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email given in...

Model validation has changed in Phalcon 3.0. In Phalcon v2 you had to do

```
public function validation()
{
    $this->validate(
        new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email(['field' => 'email']);
    );

    if ($this->validationHasFailed() == true) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validation` is deprecated in v3 and you should use `Phalcon\Validation` instead. Just alter your code to the following:

```
public function validation()
{
    $validator = new Validation();

    $validator->add(
       'email', //your field name
        new Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email([
            'model' => $this,
            'message' => 'Please enter a correct email address'
        ])
    );

    return $this->validate($validator);
}
```

Maybe the DevTools haven't updated this part yet, I am not sure.